# Declaring a 2D array with 2 for loops: Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

The question is:

Create a method `display2DArray()`.

a) Inside the method, declare a 2D array that will hold the following integers:

```
{10,20} {11,21}
{15,25} {17,28}.
```

b) Display this information using two `for` loops.

```
public static void display2DArray()
{
    int[][] arrays = new int[][]
    {
        {10, 20}, {11,21}, {15,25}, {17,28} 
    };
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; i < 1; j++)
        {
            System.out.println(arrays[i][j]);
        }

    }
}
```

This is what ive come up with, but its not correct.
Can someone tell me what i need to be doing?

Comment: What was the question? What is not correct and what is the error that you are getting?.

Comment: Homework Spotted @Daniel2233

Comment: @VikrantKashyap, the problem isn't that it's homework. Refer to Prashant's comment.

Comment: @VikrantKashyap he has made a decent attempt to solve the problem and posted his solution which is just a couple of minor changes away from the correct solution. No downvote needed IMO.

Comment: no downvote created by me @rgamber Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there!

Few things: 
1) Typo - In your inner for loop, you are using an "j" instead of "i".
2) The same "j" must be `j<=1` OR `j<2` because you have 2 columns i.e. 2 elements in each sub-array. So the indexes will be 0 and 1.
3) In your outer for loop, you are using `i<3`. Since you have 4 rows i.e. 4 sub arrays, your indexes will be 0,1,2,3. So you need to use `i<=3` OR `i<4`.
4) You can print an empty line in the outer for-loop for a better display.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) // Since you have 4 rows, indexes would be 0,1,2,3
{
    for(int j = 0; j <= 1; j++) // Since you have 2 columns, indexes would be 0,1
    {
        System.out.print(arrays[i][j]+","); // Print each row i.e. sub-array
    }
    System.out.println(""); // Print an empty line after each row
}
```

This gives you the output:

> 10,20,
>   11,21,
>   15,25,
>   17,28,

Comment: Ahhh! there we go. This  helped me alot, giving me space to show the integers. thanks alot! I knew i was close just needed some basic reviewing!

Comment: Great! Just in general, be careful about the for loop constraints i.e. < and <=. Good luck.. Make sure to accept the answer that works for you for future readers of this question.

Answer (score 0):

In your second for loop, you have "i < 1" instead of "j < 1"

Answer (score 0):

Use j in second array

```
public static void display2DArray()
{
    int[][] arrays = new int[][]
    {
        {10, 20}, {11,21}, {15,25}, {17,28} 
    };
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            System.out.println(arrays[i][j]);
        }

    }
}
```

Also the boundaries were wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j <= 1; j++)
                {
                    System.out.println(arrays[i][j]);
                }
            }
```

1.) second for loop condition check is j< 1 not i< 1
2.) first for loop condition check is  i<=3

Comment: For some reason It only displays the first part of the integers (e.g. 10, 11, 15, 17) and not the second part. Do you know why it might be doing this?

Comment: replace j<1 with j<=1

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem with the inner loop the you used . You used `i` instead of `J`. So, Your loop will not give you the result as you Expected.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j <= 1; j++) //use j instead of i here.
    {
        System.out.println(arrays[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Thanks